# Add adds/images in between paragraphs using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say, I have something like this:

```
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br/> Duis aliquet imperdiet nunc. Duis vel ipsum sed dui imperdiet auctor. 


</div>
```

I want to add an image before the `<br></br>` tags. How to do it using JQuery?
JQuery's append, prepend, after and before seems to be of no use. Please help

Comment: `<br />` should be used, you need `before`

Comment: The `.append()` and `.prepend()` will append something within the opening and closing tags, not before the opening tag or after the closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="lorem">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br /> Duis aliquet imperdiet nunc. Duis vel ipsum sed dui imperdiet auctor.
</div>

$('.lorem br').before(imghtml);
```

Or you can use

```
$('.lorem br').insertBefore(imghtml);
```

Make sure you replace the jquery selector above with something specific, most of the time there are a lot of break tags in pages, and you don't want the image you're trying to place to be inserted everywhere in your page.  I would suggest you target the paragraph you want to do that to by using a class or an ID tag.

Updated after reading your comments:

Add a class attribute to the targeted 
 tag so that you can specifically target it in your jQuery selector.  Something like this:

```
<div class="lorem">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br class="targetedbr" /> Duis aliquet imperdiet nunc. Duis vel ipsum sed dui imperdiet auctor.
</div>

$('.lorem br.targetedbr').insertBefore(imghtml);
```

Comment: What if my page has numerous <br> tags, and i want to insert before only one, i can't add an id field to that, because all the content between the <div> and </div> is being shown from the Database (including the <br/> tags)

Comment: You can target it using the '[.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)' in javascript, like this: `$('.lorem br:eq(0)').before(imghtml);` if you know which one exactly in the div, or you can assign a class to the <br /> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to close `<br>` tags, and they should also be formatted `<br />`

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9j70mxsz/) for how to do it.

```
$('br').before('<span style="background-color:red; color:white">Image Here!</span>')
```

---

In response to your question, you can add `.first()` to select the first element.

http://jsfiddle.net/9j70mxsz/1/

---

In response again, the `:nth-child(n)` selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/9j70mxsz/2/

Comment: What if my page has numerous <br> tags, and i want to insert before only one, i can't add an id field to that, because all the content between the <div> and </div> is being shown from the Database (including the <br/> tags)

Comment: Is the <br /> you're trying to target, the first one?  What's special about that <br /> tag?

Comment: There may be numberous <br/> tags before the targeted <br/> tag. Then .first() will not work!

Comment: @user3891791 I've updated to reflect this, but I think you have a bigger problem. You'll have to define where you want the image, and what image you want for each database-called file. This is basically as much effort as updating the database itself.